# Vinagre (Remote Desktop Viewer for GNOME) isn't working out of box(

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, gnome3, centos-7

I'm trying to use `Remote Desktop Viewer` to connect to remote server. I opened `Remote Desktop Viewer`, switched `Protocol` to `RDP` then entered my `Host` and my `Username` and clicked `Connect`.

```
gnome-session: Password: connected to uftwfbkpsvr02:3389
gnome-session: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
gnome-session: @           WARNING: CERTIFICATE NAME MISMATCH!           @
gnome-session: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
gnome-session: The hostname used for this connection (XXXXX)
gnome-session: does not match the name given in the certificate:
gnome-session: XXXXX
gnome-session: A valid certificate for the wrong name should NOT be trusted!
gnome-session: Certificate details:
gnome-session: Subject: CN = XXXXX
gnome-session: Issuer: CN = XXXXX
gnome-session: Thumbprint: 53:7b:c6:f6:b9:60:65:67:44:ea:06:56:c8:63:5b:a0:a1:6c:de
gnome-session: The above X.509 certificate could not be verified, possibly because you do not have the CA certificate in your certificate store, or the certificate has expired. Please look at the documentation on how to create local certificate store for a private CA.
gnome-session: Do you trust the above certificate? (Y/N)
gnome-session: Error: Could not read answer from stdin.
gnome-session: SSL_write: Failure in SSL library (protocol error?)
gnome-session: Authentication failure, check credentials.
gnome-session: If credentials are valid, the NTLMSSP implementation may be to blame.
```

I'm using:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

---

I Google for this issue and found following that looks like matching what I'm describing:

- [Bug 1062213 – Vinagre cannot open RDP sessions](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1062213)
- [Bug 724135 – Add options to ignore certificate and to disable NLA](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724135) (Thanks to @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 for pointing it out as well)

I *CAN* also use another tool to do `RDP` session, but I was wondering if someone has another solution for `Remote Desktop Viewer` itself.

Comment: What version of the RDP is the host using?  Which versions does the client support?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm using `vinagre-3.8.2-4.el7.x86_64`, which is latest available version for CentOS 7.

Comment: That's not what I meant by the RDP version; there are different versions of the Remote Desktop Protocol.  Also, it looks like you may have hit [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724135), have you investigated that yet?  A simple Google for your SSL-wirte error turned up that link, plus lots of other ideas/suggestions.  What have you tried already?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I `Google` it too) _AND_ I found some info about this bug as well even on redhat's site, however none of that address `Remote Desktop Viewer` itself, and as a workaround I was able to connect using `xfreerdp` and/or other clients as well, but that's not why I'm here)

Comment: So you're suggesting that the bug I linked, which is linked as the cause of [this Redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1062213) is not the same problem you have?  Even though they are talking about the same program, and showing the exact same results?  Partly what I'm driving at is that we can't read your mind, so we have no idea what research you've done, or what repairs you've already attempted.  Please edit your question to include that kind of information, so we don't spend time suggesting things you've already seen/tried. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Look in the file `$home/.freerdp/known_hosts`.

Delete the server you're having issues with and try reconnecting.